# Why do i get this EOF error with py2exe?

Tags: python, py2exe

heres my setup script:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe, sys, os

sys.argv.append('py2exe')

setup(
    options = {'py2exe': {'optimize': 1}},
    windows = [{'script': "aedf.py",'uac_info': "requireAdministrator",},],
    zipfile = "shared.lib",
)
```

here is my script:

```
from os import system
message='hello'
raw_input(message)
system('start')
```

when i run it i get this error in the logfile:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "aedf.py", line 3, in <module>
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

how do i fix this and what is the probleme?

Comment: What version of Python are you using? Second question, that may be a bit dumb but just to check: is your script working when launched directly as Python script?

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem but you are creating a windows executable, but `raw_input` requires a console input. Try changing `windows` to `console`.

Comment: Ya Avaris that fixed it...if you wanted to put this as an awnser i will accept it